# If element attribute does not contain anything in a particular array, do something

Tags: jquery

I have an array that is dynamic and changes often, so pretend it looks like this right now:

```
var myArray = ["red","blue","yellow"];
```

And I have some items that can be tagged with multiple words in a data attribute:

```
<li data-color="red blue yellow"></li>
<li data-color="purple pink"></li>
<li data-color="blue pink"></li>
<li data-color="red"></li>
```

I want to hide items that do not contain anything in myArray:

```
$(li).not('[data-color~="**anything in the array**"]').hide();
```

So only this would be hidden because it has no colors that are in myArray:

```
<li data-color="purple pink"></li>
```

I am not sure exactly how to do this though. I'm normally a pretty good Googler but I haven't been able to find a question regarding this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var selector = 'li';
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; ++i)
  selector += ':not([data-color~="'+myArray[i]+'"])';
$(selector).hide();
```

Depending on the values in `myArray`, you may need to escape:

```
selector+= ':not([data-color~="'+myArray[i].replace(/"/g,'\\$&')+'"])';
```

```js
var myArray = ["red","blue","yellow"];
var selector = 'li';
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; ++i)
  selector += ':not([data-color~="'+myArray[i]+'"])';
$(selector).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li data-color="red blue yellow">A</li>
<li data-color="purple pink">B</li>
<li data-color="blue pink">C</li>
<li data-color="red">D</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
$('li').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).data('color').match(new RegExp(myArray.join('|')));
}).hide();
```